# How to remove white margin from right side of page

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive

I have converted a Html Page to Responsive page. I was checking my page in `iphone` then I found that there is some `white margin` in right side of page.

I have used below code in my code, still I am not able to remove this issue

```
body{
    margin:0%;
    padding:0%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: try "padding-right:0;" If not working then send a fiddle.

Comment: "overflow-x: hidden" is the next solution.

Comment: You better show us your html to help you better but anyway have you tried with white-space: nowrap; ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is of course using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Otherwise your css should be something like that:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  let: 0;
}
```

UPDATE: imho, usually is not a good idea to remove manually the overflow

Answer (score 0):

You have some content that is overflowing the container, you should identify the source of this by removing sections of the page until it fits correctly. The easiest way of doing this is to open the dev-tools and start selecting main sections of the site and removing them.

You should be able to narrow down the cause of the overflow from here.

Instead of masking the problem (which `overflow-x: hidden` will), you should try and resolve it. You'll probably find that the fix will be simple.